# Returning generator comprehension in function causing NoneType not iterable error

Tags: python, generator, generator-expression

I have a class with a generator function that works as intended.  A caller iterates through the yield'ed values, and never executes a `for ... in` loop when nothing is yield'ed.

```
class Repository:
   ...
   def gen_by_id(self, related_id: int) -> Iterator[Something]:
      somethings = self._related_id_to_somethings[related_id]
      if somethings:
         for something in somethings:
            yield something
```

I just learned about [generator comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/generator-comprehension-in-python), and would like to use that if possible in the generator function above.  It's really just in an effort to be more Pythonic, but there are a few other situations where they will shorten code a lot more.  I tried this:

```
class Repository:
   ...
   def gen_by_id(self, related_id: int) -> Iterator[Something]:
      somethings = self._related_id_to_somethings[related_id]
      if somethings:
         return (something for something in somethings)
```

Unfortunately, if `somethings` is `None`, my original generator function worked fine, and the caller just wouldn't have anything to iterate over -- but, my generator comprehension function returns NoneType which causes a `'NoneType' object is not iterable` TypeError.

I tried adding `raise StopIteration` to the end of the function, wondering if that might be needed, but that didn't help.  It just changes the error to that the `StopIteration` error was raised but nothing 'caught' it.

I avoid the problem by making the generator function:

```
class Repository:
   ...
   def gen_by_id(self, related_id: int) -> Iterator[Something]:
      somethings = self._related_id_to_somethings[related_id]
      if somethings:
         return (something for something in somethings)
      return ()
```

But, I'm not sure if that's correct (even though it works) since that's returning an empty tuple.  And, it seems so bizarre to me that in the working scenario, the function trails off without a `return` or `yield` so I have no idea why when code that isn't executing is changed from a `yield` to a `return` why it would have to do anything different.

I also avoid the problem by making the generator function:

```
class Repository:
   ...
   def gen_by_id(self, related_id: int) -> Iterator[Something]:
      somethings = self._related_id_to_somethings[related_id]
      if not somethings:
         somethings = list[Something]()
      return (something for something in somethings)
```

And maybe that's what I have to do, but it still feels wrong and like there must be a better way.

How can I make the generator function work with a generator comprehension?  Or, should I be leaving it in its original form and am I trying to misuse generator comprehensions somehow?  Or, is there a better way to be doing this?

I see the type my generator comprehension is creating is `Generator[Something, Any, None]` instead of `Iterator[Package]`, but I think inheritance must be involved there because pyCharm and mypy aren't complaining about a mismatched return type.

Comment: Does `yield from (something for something in somethings)` solve it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's what they tried that didn't work.

Comment: So, you could just `return iter(())` if you want the signature to be correct, which is a reasonable compromise. But really, why don't you just keep the original form? returning a generator expression (the term for a "generator comprehension") doesn't give you anything. Why try to change it?

Comment: " It's really just in an effort to be more Pythonic," Using a comprehension isn't really more Pythonic. It is a convenience, syntactic sugar, if it isn't convenient in your use-case, it isn't Pythonic.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Maybe I shouldn't be.  If there isn't a good way to do this, I can go back to what I was doing.  There are some other situations where a comprehension would delete a few more lines of code, but I showed the simplest version here.

Comment: @user1902689 "less lines of code" != "pythonic", and in general, it is a bad metric to try to aim for.

Comment: "I see the type my generator comprehension is creating is `Generator[Something, Any, None]` instead of `Iterator[Package]`" not inheritance, rather, it is structural subtyping. An`Iterator` is a protocol, and `Generator` objects implement that protocol, i.e. *the iterator protocol*. So generators are iterators.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga *"those would be equivalent"* - What do you mean? [One works and the other fails](https://tio.run/##jY9BDsJACEX3nILlsHZjTLyCdzApY4lTmDAY09OPNja2O/27/4GXT51jND0cq/c@cMan@b0lOgG@JRmbTRyj6K19okWzcBkwu02YvnPM5ts2iu5OCWBh56uUX2zneLj@z90MnvFiygDVRSMVaZHWb4j24VqDqPcX), how is that equivalent?

Comment: @KellyBundy ahhh I see. I thought Barmar just meant `def ...(): yield from ...` I see now

Comment: @KellyBundy thank you so much for your comment.  Like juanpa.arrivillaga, I failed to understand Barmar.  I think he wrong it fine, I just wasn't careful reading it.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I wasn't aware of `yield from`, and that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.  `yield from` can directly give another generator, so `yield from somethings` works in the given scenario.  `yield from (<generator comprehension>)` also works and will be useful to me in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than returning the generator, use `yield from` to pass along the iteration.

```
class Repository:
   ...
   def gen_by_id(self, related_id: int) -> Iterator[Something]:
      somethings = self._related_id_to_somethings[related_id]
      if somethings:
         yield from (something for something in somethings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, *always* return (the result of) the generator expression:

```
class Repository:
   ...
   def gen_by_id(self, related_id: int) -> Iterator[Something]:
      somethings = self._related_id_to_somethings[related_id]
      return (something for something in somethings or ())
```

Note the added `or ()`.

Barmar's with `yield from` makes every value go through an extra generator layer, which is less efficient.

But I really think your original without a generator expression is the most pythonic.